# CodeIgniter redirect to another function when request is made by cURL

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I've got a function, "Function A", in a CodeIgniter controller that includes a redirect to another function, "Function B" to send an email when it's done gathering data. My problem is that when I enter  Function A's url into the browser, the function works as expected and the redirect to Function B also works... but Function A is called by a cURL script, and when this happens Function A is performed but the redirected Function B does not work. Is it possible to have a redirected function in this scenario (when the request is made via cURL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your CURL code? I think you use something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
```

Check this string (it should set to true):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

And you can use next thing (in stormdrain's example):

```
function first_function(){
    ob_start();

    //do stuff
    $this->second_function();
    ob_end_flush();
}


function second_function(){
    //send email
}
```

Comment: the cURL code is in it's own shell script file right now. `curl -d \
   "purchase_type=xxxx&\
   price=3.00&\
   description="\
   localhost/metrics/index.php?/checkin/dopurchase`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing any code. But, if these functions are in the same controller, you can call the other function when the first completes

```
function first_function(){
    //do stuff
    $this->second_function();
}


function second_function(){
    //send email
}
```

Comment: the function is in a separate controller, which is why the redirect is necessary

Comment: That would be pertinent information to include in the question.

Comment: No worries. There's always next time :)